# How Gamma generalized linear model with zero dependent variable value is derived?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, stata, gamma-distribution

I understand that Gamma distribution generates only positive values. And this is reflected in R `gamma` family `glm` function which does not run when the dependent variable contains zeros or negative values. However, in Stata, the `glm` procedure for Gamma family runs and gives output with estimated coefficents even when there are zeros in the dependent variable.

```
glm cost salary [pw=wg], family(gamma) link(log) exposure(exposure_time) vce(cluster unique_key)

Iteration 0:   log pseudolikelihood = -1602.3771  
Iteration 1:   log pseudolikelihood = -1579.4773  
Iteration 2:   log pseudolikelihood = -1579.3417  
Iteration 3:   log pseudolikelihood = -1579.3417  

Generalized linear models                         No. of obs      =     22,624
Optimization     : ML                             Residual df     =     22,622
                                                  Scale parameter =   .0233436
Deviance         =   195.440412                   (1/df) Deviance =    .009039
Pearson          =  504.7344288                   (1/df) Pearson  =   .0233436

Variance function: V(u) = u^2                     [Gamma]
Link function    : g(u) = ln(u)                   [Log]

                                                  AIC             =    .146258
Log pseudolikelihood = -1579.341674               BIC             =  -215625.8

                        (Std. Err. adjusted for 16,223 clusters in unique_key)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
        cost |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      salary |   .0000121   2.87e-06     4.21   0.000     6.45e-06    .0000177
       _cons |   4.112714   .1696957    24.24   0.000     3.780116    4.445311
ln(exposu~e) |          1  (exposure)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
count if cost==0
  9,265
```

It does not look like Stata drops the zero values by default.

```
glm cost salary [pw=wg] if cost!=0, family(gamma) link(log) exposure(exposure_time) vce(cluster unique_key)

Iteration 0:   log pseudolikelihood = -1299.6486  
Iteration 1:   log pseudolikelihood = -1286.4665  
Iteration 2:   log pseudolikelihood = -1286.3631  
Iteration 3:   log pseudolikelihood = -1286.3631  

Generalized linear models                         No. of obs      =     13,359
Optimization     : ML                             Residual df     =     13,357
                                                  Scale parameter =   .0232079
Deviance         =  188.1527815                   (1/df) Deviance =   .0152264
Pearson          =   286.780419                   (1/df) Pearson  =   .0232079

Variance function: V(u) = u^2                     [Gamma]
Link function    : g(u) = ln(u)                   [Log]

                                                  AIC             =   .2084899
Log pseudolikelihood = -1286.363084               BIC             =  -116241.2

                         (Std. Err. adjusted for 8,402 clusters in unique_key)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
        cost |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      salary |     .00001   2.48e-06     4.03   0.000     5.14e-06    .0000149
       _cons |    4.44726   .1527983    29.11   0.000     4.147781    4.746739
ln(exposu~e) |          1  (exposure)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Anyone has any idea why this is so? How exactly was the model generated in former case?

Answer (score 3):

The Stata output tells you that it is fitting a pseudo-likelihood rather than a true likelihood. Pseudo-likelihood is not well documented in Stata, but I think it is equivalent here to what is usually called *quasi-likelihood* in glm theory. That would mean that it is assuming a mean-variance relationship but not assuming any specific response distribution. For quasi-Gamma glms, the assumed variance function is $V(\mu)=\mu^2$.

You can fit the same sort of quasi-Gamma glm in R using:

```
fit <- glm(y ~ x, family = quasi(link="log", variance="mu^2"))
```

This code will not complain if `y` contains exact zeros, but will otherwise give identical results to a gamma glm in R.

Comment: This works with zeros in y, but produces errors for values very close to zero. I think the problem is how `glm` chooses starting values, so it might be safest to manually specify `start`.